# Variance decomposition in linear regression model

Tags: regression, variance, econometrics, linear-model

Consider the linear model $y = \mathbf{X}\mathbf{\beta} + \epsilon$.

The residual variance-covariance matrix is given by $\text{Var}(\epsilon)$.

Greene's textbook* states that:

$$Var(\epsilon) = E[Var[\epsilon|\mathbf{X}]] + Var[E[\epsilon|\mathbf{X}]]$$

**Why is this the case?**

Also, **why is this useful**?

---

*Page 62 in Econometric Analysis by William H. Greene

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance).